# to ask for vs to ask

Tags: prepositions

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/ask-and-ask-for says that "to ask" is used for questions and "to ask for/to" is used for requests (the 1st with nouns, the 2nd with verbs).

However, one of the definitions of "to ask" in https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ask is: "to speak or write to someone saying that you want them to do something, to give you something, or to allow you to do something".

Some examples given in this definition of "to ask" are:

- Can I ask you a favour?
- I'd like to ask your advice/opinion on a financial matter.
- You have to ask permission to leave.

Therefore, it seems to me that the definition of "to ask sth" given in the first link is incomplete. Could I replace "to ask" with "to ask for" in these 3 sentences above ? What about other contexts (eg to ask money, to ask ideas, to ask a new car)?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use **ask for** in the examples that you have given—you just don't *have* to.

- *"Can I **ask** you **for** a favour?"*
- *"I'd like to **ask for** your advice/opinion on a financial matter."*
- *"You have to **ask for** permission to leave."*

*Technically*, I suppose that, in the first two cases, you would use **ask for** if you were intending to obtain the advice or favour in the future, rather than straight away.   Only someone being really picky or condescending would pull you up on any of those, though.

*Asking permission* is an idiomatic concept, and is fine, but you can reasonably say either.

In your "other contexts", however, those are tangible things that you are asking for, so I would use **ask for** in those cases:

- *"Can I ask you for some money?"* is fine;
- *"Can I ask you some money?"* is clearly wrong.

### From comments:

> *"Ideas" are intangible. What about "to ask ideas"? I am trying to figure out if there is any rule when "to ask" can replace "to ask for" or if those cases are idiomatic (random)*
>
> You **ask for** ideas.

*Tangible* (my use) was not strictly correct—I knew that when I wrote it, but I couldn't think of a better word at the time.  *Specific* might be closer to what I intended, but it still does not quite convey the concept.

In the most general terms, you **ask** a *question*; you **ask for** a *thing*.  I reckon that's the closest you'll get to a *rule*, but it is nuanced.

The examples you listed above can be expressed legitimately in either manner, with no real loss of understanding, but that is because there is both a *thing* and there is the implied *intention* to ask an actual question:

- *"Can I ask you a favour?"* has the *thing* (a favour), which you can **ask for**; but it is also obviously a lead-in to a follow-up *question* (i.e., the favour that you actually want) that you are about to **ask**.
- *"I'd like to ask your advice..."* has the *thing* (advice), which you can **ask for**; but it also carries the *question* (i.e. what should I do in this situation?), which you are about to **ask**.
- *"You have to ask permission..."* has the thing (permission), which you can **ask for**; and the obvious pending *question* (i.e. can I leave?), which you then **ask**.

Compare and contrast:

- *"Can I ask you for some money?"* has the *thing* (money), but there is no pending *question* – you just want the thing.  So you definitely **ask for** the money, you don't **ask** the money.
- Same with *"Can I ask you for a new car?"* – there is the thing (car) and only the thing, so you **ask for** it.
- *"Can I ask a question?"* definitely has the follow-up question.  You certainly don't **ask for** a question (unless, perhaps, you were being interviewed, but that is an entirely different context).

This isn't rock-solid, though—especially when examining *"Can I ask you for your ideas"*.  There *is* an implicit follow-up question there (i.e. the subject you want ideas on), and I haven't got a reason for why it is OK to ***ask*** an opinion but not to ***ask*** an idea, but you definitely do have to ***ask for*** an idea and you definitely *can* **ask for** an opinion.

Given you can interchangeably use **ask** and **ask for** in all your listed cases, and only use **ask** in one case, perhaps your *rule* could be, **ask** a definite *question*; **ask for** a definite *thing* and, *if in doubt*, just **ask for** it.

Comment: "Ideas" are intangible. What about "to ask ideas"? I am trying to figure out if there is any rule when "to ask" can replace "to ask for" or if those cases are idiomatic (random).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - have updated.  It should be as clear as mud, now. :-)